# Jquery to retain the links clicked and add/remove css class after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have a page with multiple "Filters" which are basically links. Upon clicking the link, I am able to filter the results. However, I would like to add/remove class upon refresh of page when the link is clicked. I tried using localstorage but my localStorage returns null. Any help would be appreciated. I am very new to Jquery. It is probably a repeat but my situation seems to be unique as localstorage on refresh is returning null on console.

```
if (localStorage.getItem('filters')==null){
var filters={};
alert("in here");
}
else{
filters= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('filters'));
}

$(".li-filter").click(function(){

/*event.preventDefault();*/
var idstr= this.id.toString();
/*console.log(idstr);*/
if (filters[idstr] != undefined){
  filters[idstr] = filters[idstr]  +1;
}
else {
  filters[idstr]  = 1;
}
localStorage.setItem('filters',JSON.stringify(filters));
console.log(filters);
});
```

I am not sure if I need to use AJAX to retain my selected link ids.

Comment: It looks like you are storing the values in the Storage, but I don't see where you are trying to use them to restore anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a working fiddle based off of your description here : https://jsfiddle.net/7mtxw2a3/4/. I'd suggest making use of your browser's developer tools to verify the contents of your local storage after setting a value and then again on page refresh.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cached = localStorage.getItem('filters');
  var filters = cached ? JSON.parse(cached) : {};
  for (id in filters) {
    $('#' + id).addClass('cached');
  }
  $('li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('cached');
    var id = this.id.toString();
    if (filters[id]) {
        filters[id] += 1;
    } else {
        filters[id] = 1;
    }
    localStorage.setItem('filters', JSON.stringify(filters));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the other answer until it appeared to be working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cached = localStorage.getItem('filters');
  var filters = (cached) ? JSON.parse(cached) : {};
  for (id in filters) {
    $('#' + id).addClass('cached');
  }
  $('li').click(function(e) {
    $(e.target).addClass('cached');
    var id = $(e.target).attr('id').toString();
    if (filters[id]) {
        filters[id] += 1;
    } else {
        filters[id] = 1;
    }
    localStorage.setItem('filters', JSON.stringify(filters));
  });
});
```

The place to get your clicked object is `e.target`. Here's a link to the anatomy of a [Jquery event object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

However, when using JQuery and events together, there are a lot of situations where you will need to feed an element back into the selector as I've done with `$(e.target)`.

And to ask for the `id` attribute, you need then to chain the `.attr()` [method](https://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Hat tip to @Freddy for getting the fiddle started. Here's [my version of the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sr826fxw/2/).

Comment: This is awesome guys. Thank you. Although, I have one more requirement. If the link is clicked again, it should remove from localStorage and removeClass. Do we need to check if id already exists in filters before adding it.